# How can I migrate all conf from rabbitmq 3.0.4 to 3.6.0

Tags: rabbitmq

I would like to install a new rabbitmq server (3.6.0) but I have to get all my conf from another server (3.0.4)
I installed rabbitmqadmin, export the conf, import it back and ...

```
rabbitmqadmin import /tmp/rabbit.config
Imported definitions for localhost from "/tmp/rabbit.config"
```

I then try to list queues

```
rabbitmqadmin ---username admin --password *** list queues
*** Access refused: /api/queues?columns=name,messages
```

so I create an admin user but now it's empty

```
rabbitmqadmin --username guillaume --password *** list queues
No items
```

Any tip ?

Comment: It's a permission issue as guilaume (even as admin) do not have permission on the queue. So I add permission and it's OK for guillaume. It's not for all my other users :/ Did the permission / user stack change ?

Comment: Maybe https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Id6qulMk52k can help